# How to do this relative import in Python?

Tags: python, relative-import

```
folder0
 | __init__.py
 | folder1
 |  | __init__.py
 |  | folder2
 |  |  | __init__.py
 |  |  | script.py
 | folder3
 |  | __init__.py
 |  | module.py
```

How to import `module.py` in `script.py`? I tried having `from ...folder3 import module` in `script.py` and running `python script.py` in `folder2` gives me `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`. I am using Python 3.7. I have spent many hours reading many posts on the topic and it is still not working. Please help.

Comment: Specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28154841/). Solution 3 is recommended, you should set your project up as a Python package.

Comment: Thanks! A quick question on your last point: Have I already set it as a Python package by having an `__init__.py` under every folder?

Comment: No, `__init__.py` used to define a namespace in Python 2, and has been deprecated for this usage in Python 3. You will need to create either a [`setup.py` using `setuptools`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/) (additionally, [namespace packages](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/)) or using other compatible methods (such as [`pyproject.toml`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/)).